# Monotonic limit of half-open and half closed intervals are the open or closed intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$. We wish to show the following:

$$(a,b) = \, \, \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(a, b- \frac{1}{n}\right] = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[a + \frac{1}{n}, b\right) $$

$$[a,b] = \, \, \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left[a , b + \frac{1}{n}\right) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(a- \frac{1}{n}, b\right]$$

Naturally for these to be a proper interval we need $a \leq b$. My initial intuition is to consider the monotonic limit of sets, $E_n \uparrow E$ or $E_n \downarrow E$. Where clearly the first constructions are of increasing sets since for example $(a, b -1] \subset (a, b-\frac{1}{2} ]$.  If we define $E_n = (a, b - \frac{1}{n}]$, then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  E_n = E = (a,b) \qquad \text{where clearly} \, \, \, E_n \uparrow E$$
$$\text{Thus,} \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} E_n =  \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a, b - \frac{1}{n}] = (a,b) $$
Similarly for the left endpoint limit we have that, $[a + 1 ,b) \subset [a + \frac{1}{2} ,b) $.  So we arrive at the related consequence, defining $E_n = [a + \frac{1}{n} , b)$, then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  E_n = E = (a,b) \qquad \text{where clearly} \, \, \, E_n \uparrow E$$
$$\text{Thus,} \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} E_n =  \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a + \frac{1}{n} , b) = (a,b) $$

Since a decreasing monotonic limit of sets, $E_n \downarrow E$, corresponds to the intersection limit we can simply alter these arguments *mutatis mutandis* to arrive at the second statements.

**BUT**, how do I suffuciently prove that these two limit sets are equivalent? Or have I already shown that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You’re making it much too complicated. Just show directly that $x\in(a,b)$ if and only if $x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(a,b-\frac1n\right]$, and similarly for the other three.

Comment: Fair point! I'm working through the problems in a probability text and figured I should focus on the tools presented in that section. You're definitely right that showing $x \in (a,b)$ iff $x \in \, \bigcup (a, b - \frac{1}{n} ] $ combined with $x \in (a,b)$ iff $x \in \, \bigcup [a + \frac{1}{n}, b)$ would do it. Perhaps I'm just rusty at maths right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a simpler way.  If $x \in (a, b)$, then $a<x<b$.  Thus there exists some $\varepsilon$ such that $b-x=\varepsilon$.  Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $b-x=\varepsilon \geq \frac{1}{n}$.  Rearranging this you get $x\leq b-\frac{1}{n}$.  So $x \in (a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$ for $n \geq N$.  Thus $(a, b) \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a, b-1/n]$.

For $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a, b-1/n]$, then there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in (a, b-1/k]$.  That is, $a<x\leq b-1/k<b$.  So $x \in (a, b)$.  Thus $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a, b-1/n] \subseteq (a, b)$.  Hence $(a, b)= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a, b-1/n]$.

A similar proof gives the other union.  Likewise, a similar kind of proof gives the intersection, though you may want to consider contradiction for one direction.